# How do I refresh the UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm having a issue, where do I update the UI across two UserControls? I can tell that the changes are being made, because I placed breakpoints throughout my code, however the changes aren't reflected on front end. How should I refresh the UI?

Comment: There are lots of duplicates for this one, but I've selected one that is relatively concise.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the bound properties using either dependency properties or `INotifyPropertyChanged`.